# .Net Core Nuget Package Version mismatch: Two packages have references to different versions of the same dll

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently I have a ASPNet.Core web application with 2 nuget packages that reference different versions of the same dll.  The web project works fine, but when I add a reference in a `Unit Testing` project to the `Web` project, I get this compile error.  Something is clearly solving these dll differences because the web project compiles without issue.  It's only when I add a reference to the web project to add tests does the below compilation error occur, and only in the unit testing project.

> Assembly 'KII.Web' with identity
>   'KII.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options,
>   Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Options' with identity
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'    KII.UnitTests
>   C:\Projects\kii\web\src\Tests\KII.UnitTests\Controllers\HomeControllerTest.cs

Additionally, I also have this build error in the Unit Test project.

> Assembly 'KII.Web' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, which has a higher version than referenced assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures' with identity
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=1.0.3.0

Essentially the web project has this

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0` has a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.2.0`
- `KenticoCloud.Delivery 10.0.1` has a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.1`

Things I've tried

- clean/rebuild
- manually delete bin directories
- add [binding redirects](https://blog.rytmis.net/2016/03/29/asp-net-core-and-assembly-binding-redirects/) in app.configs in both unit testing and web projects
- Update KenticoCloud.Delivery to `11.0.0-beta1`

Since this is .net core, there are no `hintpaths` that I can tweak in the `web.config`.  I don't think checking the GAC for an old version/updating it is going to work because .net core doesn't use the GAC. Since the dll in question is a sub-dependency of nuget packages, I cannot update the nuget packages to resolve.

[Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628060/error-cs1705-assembly-uses-system-web-mvc-version-5-2-3-0-which-has-a-higher)

Comment: have you considered downgrading your application to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 which would eliminate your issue.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay doing this resolved the error, but I had 2 dll errors.  The other remains. Assembly 'KII.Web' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.1.1.0, which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=1.0.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to directly install the latest version of the one of the shared package dependencies `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures version 2.2.0` in the Web project.  Adding a direct dependency on this package allowed the unit test project to resolve its dependencies correctly.

Added this package dependency in KII.Web.csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
```